# android, ios and php encryption/decryption

Tags: php, android, ios, encryption, private-key

I am developing a mobile application in `android` and `ios` which needs to communicate with a server in `php`.I need to make sure that the communication is secure. I know that I can use `ssl` but I don't think it's worth to buy an `ssl` certificate for this project.

So I would like to encrypt the data in the mobile application, and decrypt it server side.
I found this for [android/php](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php). But what about `ios`? How could I implement this class?

Comment: SSL certificates are cheap. If you need to make sure the communication is secure then it **is** worth buying one.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am also looking for the same, so far I managed to implement encryption between android/php, ios/php, android/ios but sadly I can't make it work with the 3 at the same time.

Comment: No.I have decided to buy an SSL Certificate instead.